# Blank content area in google cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

When I log in into my google cloud console, it doesn't show any services/resources I created. I cannot also create any new service/resource. Please check the image. What is the issue?[image]

Comment: Open the browser debugger. Refresh the page. Do you see warnings/errors in the Console and Network tabs?

Comment: @JohnHanley actually, there are few errors in the console and network tab. EG :  - https://cloudusersettings.pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/CONSOLE_NAV_HIDE_PRODUCTS?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Please do not use links to external resources to provide information. Put the information in your question.

Comment: Just to add to this, I am experiencing the same issue but it was fixed by switching browsers, from Chrome to Edge.

Comment: Brave also works.

Comment: Chrome in Incognito also works for me. Trying to clear cookies and all site data in Chrome also didn't help me.

Comment: Found the problem! A Dark Mode extension that was turned off cause this. Uninstalling the extension solved it

Comment: I can confirm by removing the Dark Mode extension, it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have deleted the service that's the reason it's showing blank content. I have created a service and then deleted i can see as below image. [image] So, can you cross check once again by clicking on the create service. Post the errors in question further .

Or else refresh the project console or browser console and give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I found out that for some reason the IAM Service was deactivated, I was able to activate it following the link in this page:

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts

After activating for my current project all the google cloud console screens started to appears again.